# Convert entries of an array to a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have numpy arrays which entries consists of either zeros or ones. For example `A = [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]`, `B= [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]`, `C= [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]` Now I want to convert them into a list: `L =['0000', '0001', '0010']`. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: It's just not converting it to a list, it's concatenating all the the terms in 1 array. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I have actually an arbitrary amount of arrays that need to be concatenate in one list

Comment: Sorry if I did not understand. A, B and C produces the list L? Please put another example to be more clear.

Comment: @HighwayJohn we can not declare list like this `C= [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]` it gives an error , instead we can do `C=[0,0,1,0]` is this assumption okay?

Comment: Yes, need a better example because the example you have given doesn't make sense. `A = [ 0,  0,  0,  0], B= [ 0,  0,  0,  1], C= [ 0,  0,  1,  0]` should give. `L =['0000', '0001', '0010']`

Comment: @user5603723 You are right. Sorry for the confusion. I dont know why i have written it incorrectly..

Comment: @KalpeshDusane Yes, that is perfectly fine! Although then I need to find a way to convert [ 0. 0. 1. 0.] to [0,0,1,0] but I guess this cant be too difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert each list to a string using `join` like this

```
def join_list(x):
    return ''.join([str(int(i)) for i in x])

A = [0, 0, 0, 0]
B = [0, 0, 0, 1]
C = [0, 0, 1, 0]

print(join_list(A))
# 0000
```

The you can add them all to a new list with a `for` loop

```
new_list = []
for l in [A, B, C]:
    new_list.append(join_list(l))

print(new_list)
# ['0000', '0001', '0010']
```

Comment: Do you know an easy fix how to convert an numpy array `[ 0.  0.  0.  1.]` to `[ 0,  0,  0,  1]`? Because with your code `[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]` gives me `0.00.00.00.0`

Comment: I've edited my code slightly to cast to an integer first, it should work now.  You could also use `arr.astype(int)` to convert the numpy array to an array of integers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to `str(int(ele))` and then join:

```
["".join([str(int(f)) for f in arr]) for arr in (A, B, C)]
```

Or since you seem to have numpy arrays:

```
["".join(map(str, arr.astype(int))) for arr in (A,B,C)]
```

Or use astype twice:

```
["".join(arr.astype(int).astype(str)) for arr in (A,B,C)]
```